# Is it possible to create a callback for tb_show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I use tb_show() in my wordpress editor after clicking my custom shortcode button.

tb_show("My Shortcodes", "my-custom-panel.html");

where tb_show is out of my control.

How can I bind events for a button within my-custom-panel.html after the page loads?

I have a restriction that I can't put the javascript within "my-custom-panel.html".

Thanks

Comment: $(window).load(function() { /your code here });

Comment: I want to add bindings for a button within "my-custom-panel.html", so putting your code will not work since content of my-custom-panel is not in the DOM yet.

Comment: You can try setTimeout(function() { binding here }, time you need to get the panel loaded);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a delegated handler for the button that is within your `my-custom-panel.html` even if it's not loaded yet in the `DOM`, for example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'your-element-id-class', function() {
    //...
});
```

If you load the content dynamically after `DOM` has loaded then still this will work. I've used `click` event for the example tho.